# VB.NET/VB6 Process.GetProcessesByName("process").Length | Alternative, for VB6?

Tags: vb.net, process, vb6, count

I tried to look for a while for this, but couldn't find it.

Is there any simple way to check process count in VB6?

In vb.net it's simple, like If Process.GetProcessesByName("testprocess").Length < 2 Then... etc.

Looking for something short and simple.

Hopefully somebody knows an simple and short way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMI can assist;

```
Dim objWMIService As Object, items As Object, item As Object, count As Long

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")
Set items = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'chrome.exe'", , 32)
For Each item In items
    '// cant count so loop
    count = count + 1
Next

MsgBox count & " instances"
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not very good vb6 coder so that doesn't help me much. Could you post a direct example for this: If Process.GetProcessesByName("testprocess").Length < 2 Then MsgBox("There's less than two processes!")

Comment: replace `MsgBox count & " instances"` with `if (instances < 2) Then MsgBox "There's less than two processes!"`

Comment: Thanks. Now I need to find where I can close this :p

Comment: @user2667719 If you are looking to shut down a process from VB6, try [this](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/dd200109.asp) from Karl Peterson